# What are possible ways to unit test this method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I am currently learning how to use the unittest module. I have a minesweeper like board as an object in the form of the class below:

```
class Grid:
    ''' class to represent grid sizes. '''
    def __init__(self, width: int, height: int, margin: int, rows: int, columns: int):
        ''' 
        width: int, in pixels
        height: int, in pixels
        margin: int, in pixels
        row: number of squares along y axis
        columns: number of square along x axis
        '''
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.margin = margin
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.grid = [[0 for _ in range(self.columns)] for _ in range(self.rows)]

    def gridDraw(self):
        '''draws the grid for the game board'''
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                color = white.rgb()
                if self.grid[row][column] == 1:
                    color = green.rgb()
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                                color,
                                [(self.margin + self.width) * column + self.margin,
                                 (self.margin + self.height) * row + self.margin,
                                 self.width,
                                 self.height])

    def size(self):
        '''returns width, height, margin values '''
        return(self.width, self.height, self.margin, self.rows, self.columns)
    
    def gridVal(self):
        '''returns grid value'''
        return(self.grid)
```

My question is, how could I go about doing unit tests on this gridDraw method? It doesn't really fall under how I would normally test outputs with assertEqual() functions and the like. My test class is as follows thus far:

```
class GridTest(unit.TestCase):

    def test_gridDraw(self):

    def test_size(self):

    def test_gridVal(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

For `test_size` and `test_gridVal`, you can simply create a Grid object and call `size()` or `gridVal()`, then assertEqual if its return value is as expected.

Here's a pseudocode:

```
def test_size(self):
  grid = Grid(...)
  assertEqual(grid.size(), ...)

def test_gridVal(self): 
  grid = Grid(...)
  assertEqual(grid.gridVal(), ...)
```

---

For `test_gridDraw`, it's slightly more difficult, you needs to override the pygame class either by adding a fake subclass or mocking it. Then, you sense the fake or mock object to see if its `rect()` method has been called with expected params.

Alternatively, you can break down `gridDraw()` into `getRects()` and make its caller to call `pygame.draw.rect` so you can separate your code from pygame call and make your code easy-to-test.

Here's a pseudocode of the original code:

```
# Replace gridDraw with:
def getRects(self):
  rects = []
  for row in range(self.rows):
    for column in range(self.columns):
      ...
      rects.append(...)
  return rects
```

The caller of gridDraw will instead do this:

```
for rect in grad.getRects():
  pygame.draw.rect(rect)
```

Finally, the code of `getRects` looks like this:

```
# Instead of test_gridDraw, we do:
def test_getRects(self):
  grid = Grid(...)
  assertEqual(grid.getRects(), ...)
```